# iOS Distribution Method for Free Company App

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

I've looked for hours at other similar questions, but not sure if the other answers apply in my case, and things have changed since I last did this:

I am a sole trader writing an iPad App for an Agency. The app is ultimately for a Company they are working for.

The app will be distributed free to a small number of employees in the Company (<30);

Its a hybrid app, much of the code running as javascript in a webview. Ideally I wish to avoid Apple review of the app during distribution as this is an unknown to me.

I also do not wish to release the source code to Agency nor Company.

What's my best option for distribution? Ad-hoc? Set Company up with an Enterprise account? VPP?

I would use Ad-hoc, as it seems simpler, but not sure what happens after 1 year expiration...

Be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: I should have added that this app needs to be privately distributed and should not be visible (or at least usable) to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Apple Developer Enterprise Program (299 USD/year)

1. Ad Hoc

   - You can distribute your app to limited number of registered devices, but you need to sign every year before your provisioning profile expires, if you don't sign your app again, it will start to crash on opening after expiration date.
2. In House

   - You can distribute your app without any device limit, but you need to sign your app every year.

If you have Apple Developer Program (99 USD/year)

1. Ad Hoc

   - Same as enterprise program
2. App Store

   - Once you submit and release your app, you don't need to sign again.

I think your best choice is distributing your app via App Store if the company is okey with it. Review process is not a big deal after all, you can shape your app according to rejections reasons.

Comment: I realise I'd need the hardware ID of each device for ad-hoc, but is there any other reason why App Store better than ad-hoc? Are app updates dealt with differently? I need to make it private - is that possible this way? You also didn't mention Volume Purchase Program - is that because its not good for this scenario? I ask as Apple keep pushing this approach when I ask them.

Comment: Another option with the standard developer program membership is a B2B app; your app is still reviewed by Apple but it is only available to be "purchased" (price can be free) by volume purchasers you nominate. The purchaser can then distribute the app to their employees through an MDM or by providing iTunes redemption codes. The app is not visible in the store generally. If the app is only of use for a specific companies employees then it is likely that Apple will not approve it outside of the B2B program.

Comment: App Store is better because, you don't need to struggle with hardware ids and provisioning profile expirations, also users receive updates automatically. I did not mention about volume purchase because it requires MDM solution -> http://www.techradar.com/news/software/business-software/7-mobile-device-management-solutions-you-need-to-know-1252969

Answer (score 1):

**Apple Developer program - Adhoc Distribution**

- Cheaper ($99)
- No Appstore review needed
- Supports up to 100 device (device list can be modified yearly)
- Need to rebuild with updated provisioning profile when new device is added
- Need to rebuild the app on yearly basis when provisioning profiles expire
- OTA can be used to distribute the app to users

**Enterprise Program - In-house Distribution**

- Expensive ($299)
- App can be installed into any device without a device limit (no rebuilding required)
- Need to rebuild the app on yearly basis when provisioning profiles / distribution certificate expire
- No Appstore review needed
- OTA can be used to distribute the app to users

I would go with Apple developer program since you user base is around 30 and its a cheaper option.

Answer (score 0):

Have You looked at:

https://www.diawi.com/

Or

https://www.installrapp.com/

?

Note: You must register their devices to your Apple account first